# What is the best threading choice in an Android application for a RESTful API passing JSON data?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I am new to Android.  I’m attempting to write an application which will display multiple pieces of information about open stores.  I get that information using a RESTfull API which passes JSON data.

Here is my question: What is the best service/threading implementation choice?
Here are my product requirements:

•   I want to encapsulate all the API and JSON into a class that one or more Android “Activities” can call.  I think this might dictate a service but this service will only need to run when my application is running and will not be accessible by other applications.  The user will be required to authenticate into the remote system via the RESTfull API.

•   It will have to be on a separate thread because of the possibility of the API calls taking too much time.  I don’t think it will need to be multi-threaded since I don’t see more than one “Activity” will be interfacing with the service at a time.

•   The service should look at caching some of the information it gets back so that when an “Activity” makes a call (“GetStoreList” for instance), it could return a list of stores it already queried earlier.  I’m not sure if I should keep this information in memory or try using the SQLite functionality in Android.  I could have several hundred stores in the list with ten to twelve other pieces of information associated with each store.  Some of this information would be displayed in the “Activity” list view and some won’t.  Since I don’t have any experience with SQLite, I’m not sure what the performance cost would be over storing the information in memory.

•   There will be about a dozen or so methods that the service will need to encapsulate.  For instance: once I get the store list, I may want to call the API again to find out if the store is currently open.  Some of the information passed will be custom classes and therefore would require “Parceable” class definitions if I have to use IPC’s as part of my solution (if I understand the Android documentation correctly).

•   I would also like to “Lazy-load” the list into my “Activity” so that I don’t have to wait for the full list before updating the user interface.

Possible Solutions (this is all guessing, so please don’t crucify me… that’s why I’m asking the question):

1. I could use a class extended from “Service.”  It would have to handle the threading itself so that long internet calls via the RESTful API wouldn’t hang the system.  Alternatively, I could do the thread manipulation first and call the API with the assumption that I can take as much time as I want.  I think I would need to implement communication between the “Activities” and the service via IPC’s.  This seems a little complicated to me.  I’m not sure if I can use the “Messenger” class.  It looks easier than the AIDL stuff.
2. I think I could use an “IntentService”.  This would automatically create a separate thread and queue messages/tasks.  I think I could communicate with the service (to get the lists of stores for instance) by “Binding” to the service.  The problem I see is passing data back and forth and I’m not sure how I would cache the data between calls to the API since the service terminates after making the API call.

Anyway, I’d rather learn from someone who has already done this type of app instead of doing it the wrong way and coding it twice.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why not just use a contentprovider?

Answer (score 0):

[**AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html) was made just for stuff like this. There's a fairly comprehensive (but complex example) [**here**](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html). Also, one of my favorite [**Google IO videos**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) gives a pretty good overview of how to use it.

Comment: I really like the Google IO video.  What would be really helpful is sample code for the 3 designs discussed in the video.  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know about the first two, but the last one is pretty well represented in the example I linked to above.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is almost exactly the same as ours in my previous project. Here's what we came up with (I'm sure it's not original, but is patterned from one of those google io videos too)

- A Service handles the request-response of RESTful calls to the server. This is triggered by the activity calling `startService(Intent)` that includes the parameters in a Bundle included in the intent. The Bundle contains information as to what API will be called, and what parameters are included.
- The Service doesn't directly pass the result to the activity - instead it writes the result to an sqlite database. The activity will know that the transaction is finished by observing the db (via `ContentObserver`). Similarly, the Service can notify the activity once a transaction is completed via broadcast; the activity can catch this by registering a `BroadcastReceiver` - however the resulting data should still not be directly passed to the activity via Bundle, as there may be cases where the data is too large for the Bundle to contain (there's a limit for the length of a String that can be included in a Bundle) - you still want to put the result in the Provider. The activity should query for the data as soon as the Service notifies the activity that the result is there.
- Additionally, you can include a "success" or "fail" flag in the Broadcast that the Service will throw for the Activity, so it will know if it still needs to query for result - this removes an additional overhead for failed transactions.

If you need to ask, No we didn't use AIDL for this architecture (but we did use it on another module that does facebook/ym chat over xmpp).

The "lazy-loading" I think can be asked in a different question, as it is an entirely different process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Do you have any sample source that lays out the way you did this? I like the simplicity of your approach.